# ConfigurationManager not saving value in app.config

Tags: c#, winforms, system.configuration

I have this statement, that's supposed to set the value of a key in my config:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Volume"] = volumeNumSlider.Value.ToString();
```

But it does not save the value when I relaunch the application.

This is my app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
       <add key="Volume" value="7"/>
       <add key="Keyval" value="Z"/>
   </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That will not update it, you have save the changes back to config file following way:

```
Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
configuration.AppSettings.Settings["Volume"].Value = volumeNumSlider.Value.ToString();
configuration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

Comment: Alright, I'm trying that, but I get this error:http://puu.sh/o23d2/68a147e335.jpg

Comment: you have to set the ``Value`` property

Comment: ``Settings["Volume"].Value``

Comment: Alright that worked, thanks a bunch!